# Concate after Choose XSLT1.0 or 2.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Still new to this forum and XSLT, already searched but could not find the correct solution.

i am trying to get the right concat after the choose, if i match the condition 208 or 906 is still get LX1234 as combination, it always ends up on the otherwise as solution. the XSLT is build in 2.0 so both solutions will work for me.

```
<xsl:for-each select="XXX/Envelope/PickingList/Line/Lot">
                <articleLine type="tag">
                    <articleCode>
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="XXX/Envelope/GLN_Supplier =208">

                                 <xsl:value-of select="concat('AV',../ArticleCodeSupplier)"/> 
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="XXX/Envelope/GLN_Supplier =906">

                                <xsl:value-of select="concat('KR',../ArticleCodeSupplier)"/> 
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                 <xsl:value-of select="concat('LX',../ArticleCodeSupplier)"/>

                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </articleCode>
```

Edit  XML input,  thank you for pointing that out @michael.hor257k

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<XXX>
    <Envelope>
        <InterchangeControlReference>995566</InterchangeControlReference>
        <GLN_Supplier>906</GLN_Supplier>
        <GLN_Customer>541</GLN_Customer>
        <PickingList>
            <PickingListNumber>9</PickingListNumber>
            <PickingDate>2019-08-01</PickingDate>
            <OrderNumberSupplier>12345</OrderNumberSupplier>
            <OrderNumberCustomer>EDI Test 1</OrderNumberCustomer>
            <EarliestDeliveryDate>2019-10-09</EarliestDeliveryDate>
            <EarliestDeliveryTime>14:13:39</EarliestDeliveryTime>
            <LastDeliveryDate>2019-10-09</LastDeliveryDate>
            <LastDeliveryTime>14:13:39</LastDeliveryTime>
            <GLN_Supplier>215</GLN_Supplier>
            <GLN_WarehouseAddressSupplier>541</GLN_WarehouseAddressSupplier>
            <GLN_Customer>000</GLN_Customer>
            <GLN_DeliveryAddressCustomer>000</GLN_DeliveryAddressCustomer>
            <GLN_CarrierAddressCustomer></GLN_CarrierAddressCustomer>
            <DeliveryName>CLIENTNAME</DeliveryName>
            <DeliveryNameContactperson></DeliveryNameContactperson>
            <DeliveryTelephoneNumber></DeliveryTelephoneNumber>
            <DeliveryAddress>CLIENTADDRESS</DeliveryAddress>
            <DeliveryAddress2></DeliveryAddress2>
            <DeliveryHouseNumber>0</DeliveryHouseNumber>
            <DeliveryHouseNumberExtra></DeliveryHouseNumberExtra>
            <DeliveryPostalCode>1111 aa</DeliveryPostalCode>
            <DeliveryCity>PLACE</DeliveryCity>
            <DeliveryCountryISO>NL</DeliveryCountryISO>
            <DeliveryCustomsExcise></DeliveryCustomsExcise>
            <DeliveryMethod>DDP</DeliveryMethod>
            <DeliveryIncoterm>DDP</DeliveryIncoterm>
            <DeliveryIncotermCity></DeliveryIncotermCity>
            <Remarks_Pickinglist>REMARKS WAREHOUSE</Remarks_Pickinglist>
            <Remarks_Packinglist>REMARKS FREIGHTBILL</Remarks_Packinglist>
            <Remarks_Delivery></Remarks_Delivery>
            <CustomsExcise>true</CustomsExcise>
            <Test>false</Test>
            <Line>
                <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
                <EAN_Article>528</EAN_Article>
                <ArticleCodeSupplier>1234</ArticleCodeSupplier>
                <ArticleCodeCustomer></ArticleCodeCustomer>
                <UnitToPick>Fles</UnitToPick>
                <ArticleDescription>VINE WINE</ArticleDescription>
                <QuantityToPick>21</QuantityToPick>
                <QuantityToPickInOrderUnit>21</QuantityToPickInOrderUnit>
                <UnitOrdered>Fles</UnitOrdered>
                <Lot>
                    <LotCode>72</LotCode>
                    <BatchCode>3</BatchCode>
                    <YearOfProduction>2017</YearOfProduction>
                    <QuantityToPick>21</QuantityToPick>
                </Lot>
            </Line>
            <Line>
                <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
                <EAN_Article>081</EAN_Article>
                <ArticleCodeSupplier>5678</ArticleCodeSupplier>
                <ArticleCodeCustomer></ArticleCodeCustomer>
                <UnitToPick>Fles</UnitToPick>
                <ArticleDescription>CHAMPAGNE</ArticleDescription>
                <QuantityToPick>10</QuantityToPick>
                <CountryOfOriginISO>ES</CountryOfOriginISO>
                <QuantityToPickInOrderUnit>10</QuantityToPickInOrderUnit>
                <UnitOrdered>Fles</UnitOrdered>
                <Lot>
                    <LotCode>5</LotCode>
                    <BatchCode>4</BatchCode>
                    <YearOfProduction>2019</YearOfProduction>
                    <QuantityToPick>10</QuantityToPick>
                    <CountryOfOriginISO>ES</CountryOfOriginISO>
                </Lot>
            </Line>
        </PickingList>
    </Envelope>
</XXX>
```

Comment: Please show the XML input - see: [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instruction:

```
<xsl:for-each select="XXX/Envelope/PickingList/Line/Lot">
```

puts you in the context of `Lot`. From this context, the test in:

```
<xsl:when test="XXX/Envelope/GLN_Supplier =208">
```

will return false, because the **relative** path `XXX/Envelope/GLN_Supplier`selects nothing. You will get a different result if you make the path an **absolute** one:

```
 <xsl:when test="/XXX/Envelope/GLN_Supplier =208">
```

---

Of course, it would be more efficient to do this test **once** outside the `xsl:for-each` block and make the result available in a variable - for example:

```
<xsl:template match="/XXX">
    <output>
        <xsl:variable name="articleCodePrefix">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="Envelope/GLN_Supplier=208">AV</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="Envelope/GLN_Supplier=906">KR</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>LX</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each select="Envelope/PickingList/Line/Lot">
            <articleLine type="tag">
                <articleCode>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$articleCodePrefix"/> 
                    <xsl:value-of select="../ArticleCodeSupplier"/>
                </articleCode>
            </articleLine>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Dear Michael, This will work, but as you mention more efficient is always better, than again i am just starting with XSLT so i have no idea how to do that.

Comment: See the addition to my answer. Note that if each `Line` has one `Lot`, you could simplify it further.

Comment: I started with one lot for every line, but the client surprised me with the possibility of multiple lot for every line. Thank you for your time and assistance, I learned something again and hope also other people will learn something from this.

Comment: But you're not taking anything from the Lot. If a Line has two Lots, your result will show two identical `articleLine` twins.